# Add <tr> to empty <tbody> using PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm working on a PHP script that outputs HTML that is stored as a string.

I need to add an HTML table row (`<tr><td>No Results Found</td></tr>`) to all tables on a page that have no existing rows (i.e. `<table><tbody></tbody></table>`).

I couldn't use `str_replace` because there is white space (and/or line breaks) between the "empty" `<tbody>...</tbody>` tags.

Perhaps `preg_replace` would work? I have no idea how to write a regular expression for this.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm not concerned about speed or performance.

Comment: if(....) else (...)

Comment: ...or a ternary operator. Why a regular expression? This also looks to be db-related; should post your code for everything.

Comment: Sounds like a good work for our Javascript companion !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd generally echo out what you're trying to, however, because there is no code I can only give you a basic example. You need to display your code.

```
<?php

    if ($statement)
    {
        // do something
    } else {
        echo 
        "<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                No results Found.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
$results = preg_replace('/<tbody[^>]*>\v*\s*<\\/tbody[^>]*>/', '<tbody><tr><td>No Results Found</td></tr></tbody>', $results);
```